# Find the path that is used to search for executable programs?

Tags: linux, windows, shell, batch-file

So for one of my HW assignment, I must "display the path used to search for executable programs" in both Windows and in Ubuntu using a .bat and .sh file. At the moment I'm a bit confused about what exactly I must locate and print out.

Is this referring to one of the locations in the Windows %PATH% environment variable? If so, what would be the equivalent in Linux? Once I know what I am looking for printing it should be pretty simple.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Comment: Windows = `echo %PATH%`.  Linux = `echo $PATH`.

Comment: So it would just be printing the PATH variable?

Comment: \*shrug\* It's not my homework.  If you want to know the path of a specific executable, the command in Windows is `where exename`, and in Linux is `which exename`.

Comment: Alirght, Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct about windows and %PATH%.

For any Linux/Unix OS the equivalent is $PATH.

See this [wikipedia article](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/PATH_(variable)) for more details

Comment: I once bought some batteries, but they weren't included.  So I had to buy them again.